# How to clone QueryContainer in elasticsearch with nest client?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Because Elasticstack 5 requires tremendous amount of change and test, We are still using Nest 2.4.6.

If it matters, we use Visual Studio 2012, ASP.net 4.6.1, MVC 5.2.3.

Now here is our problem:

We have a QueryContainer which is being populated with queries dynamically based on the query requirements. At some point of this operation, we have to clone the QueryContainer object to have a derived QueryContainer to be able to make slightly different queries too.

Now, as we don't know the number of derived queries required at the beginning, we can not declare and populate all of them, so we really need to clone QueryContainer.

What we have tried already? (To make it clear to see the problem itself, instead of sharing the complete function, I'm giving an example)

1.

```
QueryContainer q = null; // Declared primary QueryContainer
q &= ... // Prepared primary QueryContainer
q &= ...
q &= ...
//lets say we have 3 bool queries in q
QueryContainer g = null; // Declared secondary QueryContainer
g = q; // self explanatory
g &= ... //add one more bool query to g, so g has 4 bool queries
//now q also has 4 bool queries, but we need to have it has 3 bool queries, without the one we added to g.
```

2.

Instead of this:

```
g = q;
```

We tried this:

```
g &= q; // No luck, still the same.
```

I find out that it is a bug in Nest 2.4.6 and fixed in 5.0. Since Nest 5.0 also requires lots of changes which we try to avoid at the moment, it is not possible for us to upgrade to 5.0. I guess we may have a chance if there is a workaround or a way to copy QueryContainer object.

Comment: I'm not following why you need to clone the `QueryContainer`? I'd also be curious to know what changes would be painful between 2.x and 5.x

Comment: Hi @RussCam, if I seem to be offensive I didn't mean it, sorry about my poor english. There are several filters to filter our e-commerce catalog. There are two phases to filter. 1. Getting the result set by applying the filters user have selected and 2. Getting the alternate filters. To be able to get the alternate filters, after several filters applied, we need to clone the QueryContainer and apply additional filters on these secondary QueryContainers side by side.

Comment: Hi @RussCam, it seemed a little hard to upgrade to 5 and believe me we tried. 1. Datatypes and attributes are changed. 2. some methods and ways to do have changed. 3. Even mapping is changed. Basically there is a need of full re-write in our case (at least we couldn't make it work on 5.x with small changes). After a failed attempt, we tried to go back to 2x and couldn't achieve it too and we installed the whole OS again. By the way, we are linux and elasticsearch newbie, may be this is the problem, being a newbie. I read all documentation about upgrading and breaking changes but no luck.

Comment: @RussCam can you please help me? I really need a hand...